# Redirect auto completion to alias

Tags: bash, autocomplete

So I've some aliases to avoid typing.

```bash
alias gs="git status $*"
alias gd="git diff $*"
alias gb="git branch $*"
alias gc="git checkout $*"
# ...
```

Now that makes life easier but in some moments it gets annoying because the auto completion is missing.
Is there a way to *redirect* the git auto-completion to my aliases?